# How to upload excel file to AWS S3 using an AWS lambda function in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an excel file in generated from a Lamba function, stored in the /tmp/ folder, I want to store it in a S3 bucket, I have setup the permisions and the bucket, but when I complete the function it creates an damaged excel file in the bucket, which cannot be opened.

The code I used:

```
import boto3

def uploadtoS3(filename=str):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'aws-day-ahead-estimations'
    DirName = '/tmp/' + filename
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket,Body=DirName,Key=filename)
    print('put complete')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the put_object() method, the Body parameter expects the actual content of the file, not the file path.

You can fix this:

```
def uploadtoS3(filename=str):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'aws-day-ahead-estimations'
    file_path = '/tmp/' + filename
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Body=f, Key=filename)
            print('put complete')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Another approach is to use the upload_file() method of the S3 client instead of the put_object() method.

Comment: Thank you! This was precisely what I needed, for future endeavors, if I had used the upload_file() method, then the file path would have been sufficient?

Comment: Yes file path would have been enough.